# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]' when record does exist

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms, ado.net

Im trying to read and download BLOB from MYSQL. Even though the record exist but still I keep on getting this error . Following is my code:

```
this.Time = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            String query = "Select * from event where time='" + this.Time + "'";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            String time = String.Format("{0:t}", DateTime.Today);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();   
            while (r.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text = r["name"].ToString();
                TextBox2.Text = r["Proposedby"].ToString();
                bytes = (byte[])r["proposalDoc"];    
                TextBox5.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("d");
                TextBox6.Text = r["time"].ToString();
                TextBox7.Text = r["Society"].ToString();
                TextBox8.Text = r["venue"].ToString();

            }
```

kindly tell how I can eliminate this error.

Comment: Are you sure it is not null? Add a `if(DBNull.Value != r["proposalDoc"])` before it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be that the record exists but the error tells you that the `proposalDoc` is db null. So the soultion would be to check if it is db null like this:

```
if(!Convert.IsDBNull(r["proposalDoc"]))
{
    bytes = (byte[])r["proposalDoc"];
}
```

Comment: now it is giving null exception in this statement context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

Comment: Check why your context object is null, this is causing the issue. File a separate question for this, it is not related to same issue

Answer (score 1):

`!string.IsNullOrEmpty(r["proposalDoc"].ToString())?(byte[])r["proposalDoc"] : null`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.